# More safe way to do dynamic list? (dynamic type .NET 4.0)

Tags: c#, list, dynamic, properties

I was trying to make a List with different types of objects (or another enumerable / indexed type). I didn't use to create own enumerator on classes, so I was googling more and more.

Now I am here with (probably) one of the worst idea

```
    public List<dynamic> IndexedProperties
    {
        get
        {
            // some code
            // returned list (I wrote only types)
            return new List<dynamic> { String, String, String, DateTime, DateTime, String };
        }
    }
```

So I could use it like that:

```
    foreach (var prop in data.IndexedProperties)
        Console.WriteLine(prop);
```

So, to precise the question - is this a good way to do that? (I think that using dynamic is not good at all, only in critical situation)
Can I do it more safe?

Comment: Do you know the size of list (or it's not fixed)? Then you could return the `Tuple` of items.

Comment: For your usage example you don't need `dynamic` at all. Just a list of untyped objects `List<object>` is enough. `dynamic` is for objects with unknown/mutable members and types, if you just don't know exact type you can always use base class (`object`).

Comment: Whoa... I didn't know about Tuple class... Thanks!

Comment: I was always thinking that List of objects can store only objects of the same type... what a shame

Comment: @BartłomiejSobieszek a list of derived objects and everything derives from System.Object. Pretty inefficient for value types (such as DateTime) but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're doing with the members of the list is showing a string then you can use:

```
public List<object> IndexedProperties = new List<object>();
...
foreach(var prop in data.IndexedProperties)
    Console.WriteLine(prop.ToString());
```

Alternatively, you could replace the `dynamic` type with an interface or abstract class that is augmented with a property that aggregates the `object`:

```
public class DynamicContainer
{
    public dynamic ValueMember{ get; set; }
    public item(dynamic valueMember)
    {
        this.ValueMember = valueMember;
    }
}
```

Then in your list constructor would go something like:

```
public List<DynamicContainer> IndexedProperties
{
    get
    {
        return new List<DynamicContainer> 
        {
            new DynamicContainer(stringObject1),
            new DynamicContainer(stringObject2),
            new DynamicContainer(stringObject3),
            new DynamicContainer(dateTimeObject1),
            new DynamicContainer(dateTimeObject2),
            new DynamicContainer(stringObject4)
        };
    }
}

...

 foreach(var prop in data.IndexedProperties)
    Console.WriteLine(prop.ValueMember.ToString());
```